# How to read files from two folders and avoid duplicates in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following folders that I read SQL files from and save them as variables:

```
++folder1
  -1.sql
  -2.sql
  -3.sql
++folder2
  -2.sql
```

The following code does the job well for a single folder. How I can modify this code to read not just from one folder but from two with a rule that if a file exists in folder2 than don't read the file with the same name from folder1?

```
folder1 = '../folder1/'
for filename in os.listdir(folder1):
    path = os.path.join(folder1, filename)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        continue
    with open(folder1 + filename, 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()
    query_name = filename.replace(".sql", "")
    exec (query_name + " = data")
```

Comment: As a side note, dynamically creating a bunch of variables like this is almost always a very bad idea, and doing it with `exec` instead of `globals` or `setattr` is an even worse idea. It's usually be much better to store everything in, e.g., a dict.

Comment: Also, notice that you're doing `path = os.path.join(folder1, filename)`, and then a few lines later doing `folder1 + filename` instead of just using `path` there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like follows:

```
folders = ['../folder2/','../folder1/']
checked =[]
for folder in folders:
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        if filename not in checked:
            checked.append(filename)
            path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                continue
            with open(folder + filename, 'r') as myfile:
                data = myfile.read()
            query_name = filename.replace(".sql", "")
            exec (query_name + " = data")
```

Comment: First, this does the opposite of what the OP is asking for. Second, why use a list instead of a set when the only thing it's being used for is checking for membership?

Comment: What do you mean by this does the opposite? It doesn't matter it is list or set, it uses just for check duplicate file names.

Comment: "a rule that if a file exists in folder2 than don't read the file with the same name from folder1". Your code will read the file in folder1, but then skip the one in folder2.

Comment: Yes that is what OP asked for. He wants to avoid duplicate files.

Comment: The OP asked to not read the file with the same name from folder1, and only read the one in folder 2. Your code reads the file in folder1, but then doesn't read the one in folder2. That's not the same thing, it's the opposite.

Comment: I think it is something OP should clarify, I understood it in the other way as " if a file exists in folder2 then don't read the file". In any case I will modify the code then It will work either way.

Comment: What the OP wrote is perfectly clear. You can’t just stop reading in the middle of the sentence and then complain that the half a sentence you read is ambiguous.

Comment: When I said "with a rule that if a file exists in folder2 then don't read the file with the same name from folder1", I meant that if a file exists in folder2, use it and don't use the file with the same name from folder1.

Comment: Yes, I understood now. This code goes along with your rule.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple: Do two `listdir` calls, then skip over the files in folder1 that are also in folder2.

One way to do this is with set operations: the set difference `a - b` means all elements in `a` that are not also in `b`, which is exactly what you want.

```
files1 = set(os.listdir(folder1))
files2 = set(os.listdir(folder2))
files1 -= files2

paths1 = [os.path.join(folder1, file) for file in files1]
paths2 = [os.path.join(folder2, file) for file in files2]
for path in paths1 + paths2:
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        # etc.
```

---

As a side note, dynamically creating a bunch of variables like this is almost always a very bad idea, and doing it with `exec` instead of `globals` or `setattr` is an even worse idea. It's usually be much better to store everything in, e.g., a dict. For example:

```
queries = {}
for path in paths1 + paths2:
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        continue
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    with open(path) as f:
        queries[name] = f.read()
```

Comment: If I keep the initial approach and use the first portion of your suggested code, won't I need to change line 6 of my initial code? `with open(folder1 + filename, 'r') as myfile:`

Comment: @sprogissd More simply, just `open(path)`. As I commented on your question, you’ve already used `os.join` to create that path, so why not just use the path instead of recreating the same string in a different way?

Comment: So just `with open(path, 'r') as myfile:`?

Comment: And I assume I should add this line of code before line 8: 'filename = path.split("/")[-1]. And replace both `os.join` with `os.path.join`. Am I correct?

Comment: @sprogissd I fixed the `os.path.join` (thanks for catching that). But meanwhile, you should probably use `os.path.split(path)` rather than `path.split('/')`, but yeah, that will work. Or, if you prefer, you can store a pair of (path, file) values in the lists instead of just the path.

Comment: abarnert Thanks! Why is `os.path.split(path)` more preferable over `path.split('/')`?

Comment: @sprogissd Imagine that you're later forced to use Windows for some reason (or you give your code to a friend who uses Windows), so now you have a path with backslashes instead of slashes. `os.path.split(path)` will still work. It's also conceptually a little clearer: it makes it obvious that what you're doing here is splitting a path, not splitting some other kind of slash-separated string like a URL or a US-formatted date—although in this case things are simple enough that I doubt any reader would be confused. It's usually not a big deal, but it's still a habit worth building.